# how run kivy program?

Tags: python, kivy

I wrote some program with python kivy lib but it's not working.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color

class Controller(BoxLayout):

    def welcome(self):
        wid = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        wid.add_widget(Label(text='hellow',size_hint=(1,.1)))
        wid.add_widget(Button(text='welcom',size_hint=(1,.1)))
        wid.add_widget(Button(text='khoroj',size_hint=(1,.1)))
        wid.add_widget(Button(text='rahnama',size_hint=(1,.1)))

class UiApp(App):
    def build(self):   
        root = Controller()
        return root 
if __name__ == '__main__':
        UiApp().run()
```

When I run the program, only a black window is shown, no widgets. What can be the problem?

Comment: put „self.add_widget(wid)” as last line in welcome (and be sure that welcome get a call from somwere...)

Comment: @cox in essence my answer

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN Yes, only yours is better explained. I saw it too late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

I will show two examples in this answer. The first without nested `BoxLayout`, and second with nested `BoxLayout`.
In both examples, I will use `__init__` instead of `welcome()`
You can also use `welcome()`. Read below on how to do that.

Then to the two problems:

First:

You never run the `welcome()` method in your `Controller` class.
You could eiter fix that by, running it in the apps `build` method, before you return `root`. Like this:

```
root.welcome()
return root
```

Or you could put it in a `__init__` method in the class. I will show an example of that, after I explain what the second problem here is.

The second problem is that you create a new `BoxLayout` in to your class, which allready inherits a `BoxLayout`. But you never add this new `BoxLayout` to your widget, which in this case allready is a `BoxLayout`.

So, how to fix this.
Since the class allready inherits `BoxLayout`, you dont need to make a new in this simple app. Only if you need to nest a `BoxLayout`, you would do that.

Lets say you dont need to nest another `BoxLayout`.
An example on how you do that, and use a `__init__` method:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Controller(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Controller,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # this is what you need to overite the BoxLayout's __init__ method

        # self.orientation and self.add_widget because self is the BoxLayout you inherited
        self.orientation='vertical'
        self.add_widget(Label(text='hellow',size_hint=(1,.1)))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='welcom',size_hint=(1,.1)))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='khoroj',size_hint=(1,.1)))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='rahnama',size_hint=(1,.1)))


class UiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Controller()
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
        UiApp().run()
```

Lets say you need to nest another `BoxLayout`.
You would do like this:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Controller(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Controller,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # this is what you need to overite the BoxLayout's __init__ method
        # I make this BoxLayout horizontal, and add a Button, just to show the idea of nesting
        self.orientation='horizontal'

        self.add_widget(Button(text='First Button'))


        self.nested_boxlayout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        # then we add stuff to the nested layout

        self.nested_boxlayout.add_widget(Label(text='hellow',size_hint=(1,.1)))
        self.nested_boxlayout.add_widget(Button(text='welcom',size_hint=(1,.1)))
        self.nested_boxlayout.add_widget(Button(text='khoroj',size_hint=(1,.1)))
        self.nested_boxlayout.add_widget(Button(text='rahnama',size_hint=(1,.1)))

        # but we still need to add the nested layout to the root layout. (nest it)

        self.add_widget(self.nested_boxlayout)


class UiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Controller()
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
        UiApp().run()
```

Comment: @motad333 no problem